# Logging all changes done by a user into a new sheet with username

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, logging, database, tracking

I have an excel sheet database, several users log in through different windows accounts to fill fields, is there a way to log changes and entries into a separate sheet in the same excel file.

if the above can be done, I am thinking I can just protect that sheet so users can't modify it. The purpose of this is to keep a trail of changes.

I want the audit sheet to log.
1.Date and time 
2.username of user ( each user logs into his/her own windows/Excel account)
3.Field Changed
4.Old value of field
5. New value of field

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Excel?  Prior to 2016, you could enable track changes.  This won't put it in a separate sheet, but changes are recorded.  With 2016, you need to look into co-authoring.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Collaborate-on-Excel-workbooks-at-the-same-time-with-co-authoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104

Comment: I only tried track changes but I need it in a separate sheet

Answer (score 2):

**Seems you're not familiar with VBA, neither you have demanded nor include the Tag with question, so it would be better to just use Track Changes.**

**1. To save the workbook as shared Workbook follow these steps:**

- Go to Review Tab.
- Click Share Workbook.
- Put a tick in the checkbox to allow changes by more than one user at
  a time Click OK and save the workbook if prompted.

**NB:** All changes are now automatically being logged each time the workbook has been saved.

**2. To see all changes.**

- Save workbook.
- Go to the Review Tab.
- Click Track Changes then Highlight Changes.
- Change "When" to show "All".
- Change "Who" to show "Everyone".
- Untick "Highlight Changes".
- Tick "List changes on a new sheet".
- Click OK.

**NB:** *Excel will create New sheet named 'History' and record all the changes along with Date, Time and User name.*

*I do hope this help you, just drop comment if you need the VBA code.*

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked but with 1 problem, I am unable to secure the excel file with a password is there a workaround because the file has to have a password. 

Less importantly but more for convenience, is there a way that new sheet "History" to always be there without having to generate it each time.

I added VBA to tags.

Thank You!

Comment: It's build in process so that History Sheet need to be generated every time, VBA Macro is the only remedy of it. To save the File with Pass Code, use Save as find Tool at the right bottom click it then find General Option, hit it you find Password setting Text boxes,, follow the rest part of instruction.

Comment: Thanks, I'll settle for on-demand history generation as for password protection, that didn't work. the pass. to open is greyed out. I was previously able to set passwords but got greyed out after sharing the workbook.

Comment: Let me explain one more time how to set Password for the OLD file.Open the file then click Save As (since your file is old one) for new file just click SAVE only. Find at the right bottom TOOL click it you find General Option click it, you find small dialogue box asking Password to Open and Password to Modify, fill as you need click OK, Excel will as to repeat the previous step, do it, click Ok ,,, that's All.

Comment: Thank you, It worked. the password protection had to be done prior to sharing the workbook. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Nice to hear from you that it's working,, happy to help you, keep asking. Appreciation always encourage us,, so after the vote of thanks, if you feel you just mark this as answer or vote. Have nice weekend.